# Ng-click trigger action on second click (not on first)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-click

I have following code in template:

```
  <a href=""  ng-ctrl="ThemesCtrl" ng-click="checkThemeContent({{theme}})" ng-repeat="theme in themes" ng-hide="theme[filterProp] !== filterValue" class="list-group-item">
                    <b>{{theme.name}}</b>
                    <span class="themesListIcons">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> {{theme.avg_score}}
                        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> {{theme.count_of_cards}}
                    </span>
                </a>
```

Which is calling the following method:

```
$scope.checkThemeContent = function(theme) {
        console.log("Trying to get cards for theme id: " +theme.id);
        console.log(theme);

        $scope.selectedTheme = theme;
        if(theme.count_of_cards >0) {
                $rootScope.$emit('detailDisplayed', {});
                $scope.displayedTemplate = 'detail';
        } else {
            $scope.displayedTemplate = 'empty';
        }
    };
```

Problem is that after the click is code in method executed,                     **$scope.displayedTemplate** is changed in scope, but template is not displayed, after second click is everything working fine.

I have no idea what can cause this behaviour.

Could somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Here is div where is included view based on the displayedTemplate scope:

```
 <div class="col-md-8" ng-controller="CardsCtrl">
                <!-- ADD TEMPLATE -->
                <div ng-if="displayedTemplate == 'add'" class="header" ng-include src="'/views/themes/add_theme.html'">
                </div>
                <!-- EDIT TEMPLATE -->
                <div ng-if="displayedTemplate == 'edit'" class="header" ng-include src="'/views/themes/edit_theme.html'">
                </div>
                <!-- THEME DETAIL TEMPLATE -->
                <div ng-if="displayedTemplate == 'detail'" class="header"  ng-include src="'/views/themes/detail_theme.html'">
                </div>
                <!-- DEFAULT TEMPLATE -->
                <div ng-if="displayedTemplate == 'default'" class="header"  ng-include src="'/views/themes/default_theme.html'">
                </div>
                <!-- NO CARD TEMPLATE -->
                <div ng-if="displayedTemplate == 'empty'" class="header"  ng-include src="'/views/themes/empty_theme.html'">
                </div>
        </div>
```

Many thans for any advice

Comment: 1st off change `checkThemeContent({{theme}})` to `checkThemeContent(theme)`

Comment: 2nd, try to initialize `$scope.displayedTemplate` a.e. give default value. Sounds like on start its undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is how you passed your parameter to the function . Pass it simply like 
    `ng-click="checkThemeContent(theme);"`.